# Sending hex-data via socket, is interpreted as string

Tags: python, sockets

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to use a 3rd party library/module. What I'm doing now is:

```
s.send(rtp.header_bytes + rtp.payload) 
# -> \x80!\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x00Testy
```

to send the header and the payload of a packet via tcp socket. On the receiving side:

```
conn, addr = socket_rtp.accept()
data = conn.recv(1024)
```

the data is passed to a constructor `__init__(self, bytes, length)`  and then used like this

```
self.version = (bytes[0] & Packet.V_MASK) >> 6
```

but it seems that it's interpreting the bytes array as string? I'm getting the following exception:

```
.... line 322, in __init__
    self.version = (bytes[0] & Packet.V_MASK) >> 6
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the string (`bytes`) to int, you can use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) (assuming your're using Python 2.x):

```
self.version = (bytes[0] & Packet.V_MASK) >> 6
```

or [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```
self.version = (struct.unpack('B', bytes[0])[0] & Packet.V_MASK) >> 6
```

---

```
>>> ord('\x80')
128
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('B', '\x80')[0]
128
```

Comment: This gives me: Struct() argument 1 must be string, not unicode. Also, I'm now confused why there is a '!' in the string representation...

Comment: @damian, Did you import `__future__` (`from __future__ import unicode_literal`)? Then, use `b'B'` instead of `'B'`.